# Latest time to fly out of Schengen area on a tourist visa

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

I am an Indian national on an H1B visa in US. My Schengen visa stamp has an until date of 09/01. I am flying out of Berlin 08/31.

My question is do I have an extra day for emergency as things stand. As in, do I have until 09/01 11:59 PM local time to mark my exit without any penalties.

I am just trying to see a loved one before the visa expires but do not wish to risk anything for future travels so just trying to assess risk vs reward.

Also my itinerary is Berlin>Amsterdam>NYC on the same delta ticket. Where will my exit passport control happen. In Berlin or Amsterdam

Comment: Note that even with the extra day left, it’s still cutting it pretty close these days, given the current issues in air travel and the number of delays and cancellations happening. Also, depending on the type and duration of the visa and how long you stayed in Schengen, you may be subject to the 90/180 rule in addition to the visa validity dates.

Comment: For a one entry visa, 15 days (as a ‘period of grace’) will often have already been added to the dates you applied for (Visa Code Article 24). The *until* date (1st of September) is inclusive.

Comment: @jcaron - is the situation that dire that I will not be able to find a flight out of Schengen in a 48 hour period? I do have the multi entry visa but was only in Schengen for 7 days last month so. Just squeezing another few days out :)

Comment: @MarkJohnson - mine is a multi entry visa so i am assuming inclusive means that I can fly out untill 11:59 local time on 09/01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exit controls are done in Amsterdam as Berlin-Amsterdam is a Schengen *domestic* flight and then you will connect out of Schengen in Amsterdam

And if you leave on 08/31, you definitely have a day afterwards you can stay in case of

Comment: For what it's worth, the term of art for flights from one Schengen country to another is "internal" rather than "domestic."  The distinction has little practical application in most contexts, however.